# HOWTO attach to a released App on the iPhone? not a debug version

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've tried to attach to a debug App using Xcode : Product -> attach to process, and it works.

But when I tried to attach to an App installed from the App Store, the Xcode firstly said waiting the App to launch, and when I launch the App on the iPhone, Xcode just **finished running the App on my iPhone**... nothing else.

My problem is that my app released on the App Store has a bug, I want to attach to it to debug.

Many thanks.

For the reason (@Kendall Helmstetter Gelner):

This bug is hard to track, and I have an iPhone meet it.

Comment: You're talking about Instruments, right?

Comment: No, @Undo . Instruments is easy to attach to process...

Comment: The real question is, WHY do you want to do this.  That may help find better answers, or better approaches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot debug an app store application.  It would be foolish to allow such behavior.  You don't want some random script kiddie trying to use the debugger to hack into your app.  You need to fix the problem another way.  Test your release build and confirm the differences (if any) between a normal release build and your app store build.

In short, test your release build from Xcode (build it with your development certificate).

Comment: It wouldn't be foolish if Xcode prompts you for the developer's Apple ID password to verify that it is indeed you who's debugging your app.

Answer (score 10):

"Once you have deployed your app, either through the App Store or as an Ad Hoc or Enterprise build, you won't be able to attach Xcode's debugger to it. To debug problems you'll need analyze Crash Logs and Console output from the device."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, its not possible to attach an app in release mode.

Comment: It depends on the certificate it was signed with ;).

Comment: @borrrden The app is released with my certificate.

Comment: obviously, I think release means that is has to signed with distribution profile.

Comment: @Mayank No, that is not true.  You can sign it with whatever you want.  You just can't *distribute* it without a distribution profile.

Comment: You can attach an app in RELEASE mode but you can not debug it. 
To make it run you have to uncheck "debug executable" in the RUN section of the Scheme and accept the distributon profile on your device (at the first time xcode will guide you with a message).